# upload and get files to frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multer

im having truble to get files after uploading them, i used multer in the backend and here is my fileUpload code.. i don't undrestand what's not working well n how to fix it.. any help please ?i know my code don't seems pretty, i'm a junior dev and this is my first fullstack project..
file supported (/jpeg|jpg|png|pdf|doc|txt/) thank you

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'

 
function FileUpload() {
 
    const [file, setFile] = useState([]);
    
    //const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");
 
    const saveFile = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.files)
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        //setFileName(e.target.files[0].name);
    }; 
 
    const uploadFile = async (e) => { console.log("hello")
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("files", file);
        //formData.append("fileName", fileName);
        
        
        const config = {     
    headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
}
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(
                "http://localhost:8000/imageAPI/newImage",
            formData, config 
        );
        } catch (ex) {
        }
    };
    
        return (
            <div className="upld">
                <Form.Group controlId="formFileLg" className="mb-3">
                    <Form.Label>choose your file from here</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="file" size="lg" onChange={saveFile} />  
                    <div>{file && `${file.name} - ${file.files} - ${file.description}`}</div>  
                </Form.Group>
                <button className='w-25 mb-4' size='md' onClick={uploadFile}>Upload</button>
                <img scr={file}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

 
export default FileUpload;
```

every single search i made i found the same code or similar to mine so i'm kind of stuck here

Comment: Did you want to set the state to the entire array of files like this `setFile(e.target.files)`  or you want one file like this `e.target.files[0]`, which is the first file in the list of selected files? What result you want to expected ? @laroussi torki

Comment: And as you can see in the above code, `file` is an `array` of files, so, if you want to save that file. Then, you should be iterating over the array and appending each file individually.

Comment: And again also `src` the attribute should be src, not scr in `img` tag.

Comment: consider to add some details in your code like what kind of result you want. Did you want to save the entire array of file? And you are not `handle` the response and `error` as wall.

Comment: @DSDmark i want to set one file , and the rsult expected is to upload that file and desplay it .. can you help me with an exemple to eterate over the array and append the file ? if possible and thaks a lot